# Proving $\prod_{j=1}^n(1-\prod_{i=1}^m\sin^2x_{ij})+\prod_{i=1}^m(1-\prod_{j=1}^n\cos^2x_{ij})\geq1$, for real numbers $x_{ij}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, products

I have been struggling to solve the following problem which seems to be some kind of generalized trigonometric Pythagorean identity:

> Let $x_{ij}$ $(1 \leq i \leq m$, $1\leq j \leq n)$ be real numbers, then prove that:
> $$\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(1-\prod_{i=1}^{m}\sin^2(x_{ij})\right) + \prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(1-\prod_{j=1}^{n}\cos^2(x_{ij})\right) \geq 1$$

I have tried the following induction:

Prove for $n=1$ and any $m$ and then do an induction on $n$. The base case is immediate using $1-\cos^2(x_{ij}) = \sin^2(x_{ij})$. However I have not managed to pull off the inductive step.

If anyone has a contribution it would be much apreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\sin^2x_{ij}$ is an arbitrary number in $[0,1]$, and $\cos^2x_{ij}=1-\sin^2x_{ij}$, let's rewrite your expression, with $p_{ij}\in[0,1]$:

$$\prod_{j=1}^n(1-\prod_{i=1}^m p_{ij})+\prod_{i=1}^m(1-\prod_{j=1}^n(1-p_{ij}))$$

Now, consider a matrix of independent events $E_{ij}$ on a given probability space, where the probability of $E_{ij}$ occurring is $p_{ij}$.

The first product is the probability of the event $A$: "in every column $j$, at least one event $E_{ij}$ does not occur".

The second product is the probability of the event $B$: "in every row $i$, at least one event $E_{ij}$ is occurring".

Now, we have $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.

If $A$ is false, it means that there is a column where all events occur, but then $B$ must be true. Therefore, $P(A\cup B)=1$. And finally, we may write:

$$P(A)+P(B)-1=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)=P(A\cap B)\in[0,1]$$

Hence $P(A)+P(B)\ge1$, which is exactly your inequality.